# How could I pass foreach button single value to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, button, foreach

My Javascript and Jsp code :

```js
var questionNum = $('#questionNum').val();
```

```html
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${examPaper.number_of_questions}">
 <input type="button" name="question_num" id="questionNum" value="<c:out    value="${i}"/>" onclick="doAjaxPost(this.id);" class="startTest"/>
</c:forEach>
```

but in the java script, I am getting value as 0. Anyone help me to get the value.

Comment: replace  `value="<c:out    value="${i}" ` to `value="${i}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(":input").click(function(){
   var questionNum = $(this).val();
   alert(questionNum);
   });
});
```

HTML, JSTL code to your jsp page

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${examPaper.number_of_questions}">
        <input type="button" id="questionNum${fn:escapeXml(i)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(i)}" onclick="doAjaxPost(this.id);" class="startTest"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: function doAjaxPost(qnum) {
     
     var question_num =0;
     $(":input").click(function(){
     var question_num1 = $(this).val();
     question_num = question_num1;
     
     });
     alert(question_num);  
 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "loadQuestionAjax.do",
            data: "question_num=" + question_num,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#outer").html( response );
            }
        });

Comment: I ma getting the value for question_num is 0. if that is inside click function its showing correctly. outside its showing 0 only.

Comment: Thats a problem on your Ajax function. Try to set data like this $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "loadQuestionAjax.do", data: {question_num : question_num}, success: function(response) { $("#outer").html( response ); } });

Comment: I'm glad to see it ;) Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try with fn function based on XML.

```
<input type="button" name="question_num" id="questionNum" value="${fn:escapeXml(i)}" onclick="doAjaxPost(this.id);" class="startTest"/>
```

Remember you need to import functions jstl you could do it with

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Or

```
<div xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
   ... Your code...
</div>
```

Hope it helps you, regards.

Comment: Can you tell me where should i import that jstl function.

Comment: On the beginning of the document, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_escapexml.htm

Comment: #mgamon. Thank You very much. I got the value.

Comment: You are welcome, if you hink that this is the right answer, please, click check mark. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I am producing list of buttons using foreach tag. For every button I am getting 1 as value for for the button.

Comment: Your foreach loop ends attribute isn't null, right?

Comment: <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${examPaper.number_of_questions}"> in this if i have 10 questions 10 buttons will be displayed. If i click on evry button, the value returned is 1 only.

Comment: Thats right because all your inputs have the same id `name="question_num" id="questionNum"` change the attributes.

Comment: You can loop them too `<input type="button" name="question_num${fn:escapeXml(i)}" id="questionNum${fn:escapeXml(i)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(i)}" onclick="doAjaxPost(this.id);" class="startTest"/>`

Comment: Ok then in javascript how can i get with index?

Comment: Like my last comment : `id="questionNum${fn:escapeXml(i)}"`

Comment: Please make it clear. In jsp i modified like u mentioned. In javascript, var question_num = $('#questionNum${fn:escapeXml(i)}').val();  like this i am getting. But i got value as 0.

Comment: Well, don't modify your javascript. The bug its on jsp foreach. Change your input declaration like this:  `<input type="button" name="question_num${fn:escapeXml(i)}" id="questionNum${fn:escapeXml(i)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(i)}" onclick="doAjaxPost(this.id);" class="startTest"/>` now on each click you submit inputs id, and foreach input the id will be `questionNum1`, `questionNum2`, ...

Comment: I am sorry. Again i am getting 0 only.

Comment: What value have id attribute in inspector browser?